# Css How to override <p>

Tags: html, css

This is the code I am using :

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="first_line">
    <a href="#"><div class="bouton_style_blue" id="conception" align="center"><p class="bouton_text">Conception des systèmes pilotés</p></div></a>
    <a href="#d"><div class="bouton_style_blue" id="modelisation" align="center"><p class="bouton_text">Modélisation et simulation</p></div></a>
</div>
<div id="second_line">
    <a href="#e"><div class="bouton_style_blue" id="development_control" align="center"><p class="bouton_text">Développement des systèmes de Contrôle-Commande</p></div></a>
    <a href="#f"><div class="bouton_style_blue" id="validation" align="center"><p class="bouton_text">Validation des systèmes de Contrôle-Commande</p></div></a>
</div>
<div id="third_line">
    <a href="#"><div class="bouton_style_purple" id="formation" align="center"><p class="bouton_text">Formation</p></div></a>
</div>
```

And this is the associed CSS :

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700);

p
{
  color:black;
}


.bouton_texte
{
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

The text on the button is black. I wish for it to be white, but I can't manage to override the p rule...

Comment: Change `.bouton_texte` to `.bouton_text`.

Comment: you kinda misspelled something ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
.bouton_text
{
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white !important;
}
```